# Creating models for each group in dataframe column in R

Tags: r, dataframe, grouping, naivebayes, party

I would like to create a naiveBayes model per group of values of column `TN`.
Here is the code:

```
library(party)
airq <- subset(airquality, !is.na(Ozone))
ct <- ctree(Ozone ~ ., data = airq,  controls = ctree_control(maxsurrogate = 3))
airq$TN<-factor (ct@where)
```

Here is an example:

```
> tail (airq)
    Ozone Solar.R Wind Temp Month Day TN
1     7      49 10.3   69     9  24   2
2    14      20 16.6   63     9  25   5
3    30     193  6.9   70     9  26   3
4    14     191 14.3   75     9  28   2
5    18     131  8.0   76     9  29   5
6    20     223 11.5   68     9  30   3
```

I want to build a `NaiveBayes` model per value:

```
model[i] <- naiveBayes(Ozone ~ ., data = dat[i])
```

`dat[1]` will contain lines 1 and 4 (`TN=2`) for creating first model,`dat[2]` contains lines 2 and 5 for (`TN=5`) for the second model, `dat[3]` contains lines 3 and  for third model (`TN=3`).
So finally, I'll be able to sum it up: for each unique group values in TN I'll have its model.
Like this:

```
    TN_val  model     Based on Source_Lines
1     2     model[1]   1,4
2     5     model[2]   2,5
3     3     model[3]   3,6
```

Comment: `lapply(split(airq, airq$TN), function(x) naiveBayes(Ozone ~ ., data = x))`

Comment: Hi @LAP, Thanks. How can I get  the relevant value of TN per the model?

Comment: The name of the list element will be equal to the value of the TN for each model in the list. So if you'd use `mymodels <- lapply(split(airq, airq$TN), function(x) naiveBayes(Ozone ~ ., data = x))`, `names(mymodels)[1]` would display the TN value of the first model.

Comment: Thanks again @LAP. One more question: I have an additional of airq dataframe (for testing). I would like to run (predict) the mymodels on the new data per line per TN value. How can I do it?